# How to get localized "One Letter" weekday abbreviations in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, date-format, weekday, abbreviation

If I do this

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime(2022, 5, 1); // Sunday
print(DateFormat("E").format(dateTime));
```

**Sun** will be printed out to the console. Which is what I expected.

This also works if I change the system language.

How to printout the localized **One Letter weekday abbreviation**?

e.g. **M T W T F S S**

I thought I can get first letter using "substring", but it won't be correct for all languages. For example, Spanish weekdays are: Lunes, Martes, Miércoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sábado and Domingo, and first letter for "Miércoles" is X instead of M to difference it from "Martes".

In Java you could do something like this to get the One Letter abbreviation:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE", Locale.getDefault());
simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

For Spanish the output would be **L M X J V S D**

Comment: One letter abbreviation? Could you please explain a little further and what's the problem you are facing with above code? Isn't it giving you the localised value based on phone's locale ?

Comment: Are you sure there *are* gobally recognized 1-char weekday abbreviations? I never heard about it and upon googling it found multiple one's even in the US only in use with universities.

Comment: @MidhunMP I can get "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat" but i need "S M T W T F S"

Comment: @nvoigt  As i wrote in the question above. You can do "new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE", Locale.getDefault());" in Java and it works.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way to do this in dart. You can prob do this: `DateFormat("E").format(dateTime)[0]` but not sure if that is good enough

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco  Thanks. But this works only for some languages like english or german, but not for Spanish

Comment: @SomjitGlin-Jan I don't think there is a built-in function available, also didn't find anything on intl package. All you can do is to create a map which will hold the 3 letter abbreviation as key and 1 letter abbreviation as value. It would be tedious task to handle that for all the supported language, but I don't think there is any other way at the moment

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my question. Maybe its helpful to somebody.

```
var wd = DateFormat.EEEE().dateSymbols.NARROWWEEKDAYS;
print(wd);
```

The output for Spanish language
**[D, L, M, X, J, V, S]**

This works with all languages i have tested (Japanese, German, English, Polish, Spanish, Italian etc.)

Comment: I think you can shorten this to just `DateFormat().dateSymbols.NARROWWEEKDAYS;`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on a use case, like a calendar header, it might be actually better to use standalone weekday format.

One-letter standalone format is supported with custom pattern `ccccc`:

```
var dateTime = DateTime(2022, 5, 1); // Sunday

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  print(DateFormat("ccccc").format(dateTime));

  dateTime = dateTime.add(Duration(days: 1));
}
```

That prints: **S M T W T F S**